# How to set Title for OpenFolderDialog in an Avalonia application?

Tags: c#, avaloniaui, avalonia

I'm working with `OpenFileDialog`, `SaveFileDialog` and `OpenFolderDialog` in an Avalonia application.
One requirement is to set the title to a certain string.
I achieved this for `OpenFileDialog` and `SaveFileDialog` but **not** for `OpenFolderDialog`.
`OpenFolderDialog` resists applying the title, so that only a default title according the language of the operating system remains set.

I found that in [ControlCatalogStandalone](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/ControlCatalogStandalone) the `OpenFolderDialog` works correct, i.e. the title can be set as desired.
So, I tried to reduce **ControlCatalogStandalone** to the **Dialogs** functionality and transform it to be as similar as possible to my test application.
I couldn't achieve that, but I found some clue that might help a more skilled developer to find the reason for the misbehavior of my test application.

The **Solution** and the **Project**s of **ControlCatalogStandalone** are structured and composed much different to my Avalonia test application.
In my test application the target framework is `.NET Core 3.1`.
In one Project of the **ControlCatalogStandalone** Solution the target framework is `.NET Standard 2.0`.
So, I think `OpenFolderDialog` works correct in `.NET Standard` but not in `.NET Core`.
I also think that if **ControlCatalogStandalone** was built from scratch with the current version of the `Avalonia for Visual Studio` Extension, it wouldn't produce a mix of frameworks.

Here are the relevant code parts of my test application:

MainWindow.axaml:

```
<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:DialogTests.ViewModels;assembly=DialogTests"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d" Width="200" Height="150"
        x:Class="DialogTests.Views.MainWindow"
        Icon="/Assets/avalonia-logo.ico"
        Title="DialogTests">

    <Design.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Design.DataContext>

    <Grid RowDefinitions="*,*,*">
        <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Command="{Binding OpenFileDialogCommand}" Content="OpenFileDialog"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Command="{Binding SaveFileDialogCommand}" Content="SaveFileDialog"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Command="{Binding OpenFolderDialogCommand}" Content="OpenFolderDialog"/>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs:

```
using Avalonia.Controls;
using DialogTests.Views;
using ReactiveUI;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reactive;

namespace DialogTests.ViewModels
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            OpenFileDialogCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(() => {
                new OpenFileDialog()
                {
                    Title = "Open File Dialog",
                    Filters = GetFilters()
                }.ShowAsync(MainWindow.Instance);
            });

            SaveFileDialogCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(() =>
            {
                new SaveFileDialog()
                {
                    Title = "Save File Dialog",
                    Filters = GetFilters()
                }.ShowAsync(MainWindow.Instance);
            });

            OpenFolderDialogCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(() => {
                new OpenFolderDialog()
                {
                    Title = "Open Folder Dialog"
                }.ShowAsync(MainWindow.Instance);
            });
        }

        public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> OpenFileDialogCommand { get; }
        public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> SaveFileDialogCommand { get; }
        public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> OpenFolderDialogCommand { get; }

        List<FileDialogFilter> GetFilters()
        {
            return new List<FileDialogFilter>
                {
                    new FileDialogFilter
                    {
                        Name = "Text files", Extensions = new List<string> {"txt"}
                    },
                    new FileDialogFilter
                    {
                        Name = "All files",
                        Extensions = new List<string> {"*"}
                    }
                };
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.axaml.cs:

```
using Avalonia;
using Avalonia.Controls;
using Avalonia.Markup.Xaml;

namespace DialogTests.Views
{
    public class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public static MainWindow Instance { get; private set; }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            Instance = this;
            InitializeComponent();
#if DEBUG
            this.AttachDevTools();
#endif
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            AvaloniaXamlLoader.Load(this);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm showing the last file because I wasn't able to implement the method
`Window GetWindow() => (Window)this.VisualRoot;` in my ViewModel which in **ControlCatalogStandalone** is implemented and used in the code behind of `DialogsPage` (which actually is a `UserControl`).
So, I implemented the `Instance` property which perhaps is a hack.
If you also could give me hint on best practice to get the instance of the `MainWindow` I'd be happy.

Is my problem not being able to set the title in `OpenFolderDialog` an open issue of the `.NET Core` implementation, or can you tell me how to get it working in my simple test application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar/experienced with the Avalon framework so I won't comment too much on your different setup tests. However it seems that the `OpenFolderDialog` has a bug that it doesn't set the title when being showed, atleast for its **Windows** implementation. This is reported as a issue on the github source, and seems not yet solved:

> frm.SetTitle is missing for the folder dialog:
> [Windows/Avalonia.Win32/SystemDialogImpl#L116](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/87021ec10b0111eabce75b4bcb9b5a323c29483f/src/Windows/Avalonia.Win32/SystemDialogImpl.cs#L116)

(In comparison to [here](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/87021ec10b0111eabce75b4bcb9b5a323c29483f/src/Windows/Avalonia.Win32/SystemDialogImpl.cs#L43) for FileDialog).
Reference: https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/issues/3037

Without further digging into the source, its unclear why the `ControlCatalogStandalone` example functions correctly since it appears to use the same method in #ShowAsync (used [here](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/ControlCatalogStandalone/blob/3d0ae5fb0c0535e8290854ec0e40ad72a0d25a80/ControlCatalog/Pages/DialogsPage.xaml.cs#L50)), which is defined [here](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/cb582095e4b09d2b299ad0fd0cd288ecbd6620e1/src/Avalonia.Controls/SystemDialog.cs#L64).

Comment: You are right this is a bug in the framework. I think it works for the `ControlCatalog` sample because they are using a custom styled folder picker dialog there, aren't they?

Comment: I was investigating more on this issue to show clearly the different behavior of `OpenFolderDialog` in the ControlCatalogStandalone application and in my own test application.
I already uploaded the whole sources of my test application and of the ControlCatalogStandalone application which I reduced to the Dialogs functionality, but now I think they are not needed any more.
Thank you all for your information and thank you for the new created issue.